# How do I run the dev releases of Edge and msedgedriver with Python, Selenium, and Linux in TravisCI?

Tags: python, selenium, travis-ci, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

As a side project, I wrote a Python module that's basically a wrapper for Selenium. I've tested all the functionality with Chrome and Firefox only and I'm now trying to add Edge. I'm having a problem getting my tests to pass in my Travis CI (Linux) instance and I think it's because MS Edge and `msedgedriver` are the `dev` versions in the build server, 91.0.852.0 at the time of writing this.

This is my suspicion because the tests pass on my local machine, a Windows system using the latest non-dev version of Edge and its driver, 90.0.818.41. I'm using `selenium` 3.141.0 and `msedge-selenium-tools` 3.141.3.

I ***would*** try to use the non-dev versions in the build server if it were possible, but as far as I can tell, version 91 is the earliest Edge and `msedgedriver` compatible with Linux.

To get an idea of the kind of errors I'm getting, here's a sample test script:

```py
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from msedge.selenium_tools import webdriver as EdgeDriver

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
driver = EdgeDriver.WebDriver(options=edge_options)
```

and the error I get from this is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

It's my understanding that this error happens when `msedgedriver` is not in the executable path. In Travis CI, I have the dev version of `msedgedriver` in the executable path though, which is another reason why I'm thinking the problem is because I'm using the dev releases.

Here's the relevant part of my `.travis.yml` file:

```yaml
   # Get Edge and its driver
  - curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
  - sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
  - sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list'
  - sudo rm microsoft.gpg
  - sudo apt update
  - sudo apt install microsoft-edge-dev
  - wget https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/91.0.852.0/edgedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/
  - unzip ~/edgedriver_linux64.zip -d ~/
  - rm ~/edgedriver_linux64.zip
  - sudo mv -f ~/msedgedriver /usr/local/share/
  - sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/share/msedgedriver
  - sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/msedgedriver /usr/local/bin/msedgedriver
    # Debugging statement, remove when this is figured out
  - which msedgedriver
  - echo $PATH
  - ls /usr/local/share
  - ls /usr/local/bin
```

I can tell from the stuff under `# Debugging statement...` that `msedgedriver` is in the executable path. Does anyone have any ideas on what is causing my problems or a way around them? If it helps, you can check out [the relevant pull request](https://github.com/erik-whiting/LuluTest/pull/73) in which I'm having these problems.

Thank you so much in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code to see if it works well in Linux. Please note to change the paths in the code to your owns:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions, Edge

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.binary_location = r"/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-dev"
options.set_capability("platform", "LINUX")

webdriver_path = r"/your_path/msedgewebdriver"

browser = Edge(options=options, executable_path=webdriver_path)
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Reference link:
[Python Selenium Settings On Microsoft Edge Dev On Linux](https://ayamir.github.io/posts/python-selenium-settings-on-microsoft-edge-dev-on-linux/)

Comment: the script works locally, thank you so so much! I'm off to go work it into my project. You saved me a lot of time, thanks a ton!